# Handle multiple forms in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am going to make a voting website. To get the information from a user , I divide the form into three parts – election, candidate, voter, and place the three forms on three different pages. I want to update my database table after completion of three forms. Normally I use Input façade to get form data. But here I use three different forms on three different pages. I try to use Input::all() like-

```
$data=Input::all();
```

But I need to get property of the object also like

```
Input->election_name, Input->start_time etc.
```

So, I want to save three different Input façades in three different places.  And when I need I can use them like-

```
Input1->election_name;
Input2->candidate_name;
Input3->voter_ name;
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: You must store you input data in session on submit for each form, then use this session to store your data.

Comment: I don't see a problem. Store client's info in the DB at each step, and before rendering each form, check if the prerequisite info is stored in the DB (i.e. has been collected). You might also store step # in a cookie.